# Rogue Talent: Offensive Defense

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, sneak-attack

I've seen arguments going both ways on this so I don't know how to rule this.

If a rogue with [Offensive Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/offensive-defense-ex) gets multiple sneak attacks in one round does the bonus AC stack?

Example: A level 5 rogue with sneak attack 3d6 uses two weapon fighting while flanking and gets two sneak attacks. Does this rogue gain +3AC or +6AC?

Answer (score 7):

Best I can tell, Paizo hasn't made an official ruling on this.  The last reference I can find of an official statement on this is from an FAQ post on their blog:

http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ld6h?Bride-of-the-FAQ-Attack

> Two, it doesn’t specify whether the dodge bonus stacks with itself, and because this creates a strange place in the rules where bonuses don’t stack from the same source but dodge bonuses always stack. While we haven’t reached a final decision on what to do about this talent, **we are leaning toward this solution: the dodge bonus only applies against the creature you sneak attacked, and the dodge bonus does not stack with itself.** This prevents you from getting a dodge bonus to AC against a strong creature by sneak attacking a weak creature, and prevents you from reaching an absurdly high AC by sneak attacking multiple times in the same round.

Allowing it to stack would be a bit overpowered, and I would imagine most GMs would rule this way in absence of an official ruling.

Comment: [Actual FAQ ruling](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9p1m) (although it's still not a settled issue).

Answer (score 1):

So, by the RAW, dodge bonuses always stack. So the +6 is the correct answer.

However, @Steve G points to an indecision on the Paizo forums about this very rule. And I personally agree that this can become very abusive. At level 8 with two-weapon fighting, I'm rolling 4d6 sneak attacks and I can reasonably get 3 or 4 hits, which amounts to a +12AC bonus.

Again, @Steve G points to some possible solutions, but I think they're both sub-par. Tracking the "creature hit" is a real pain, especially in a big fight. And good rogues are sneak attacking all of the time, so this becomes a constant thing to remember.

The *"does not stack with itself"* is better, but I'm not sure how to convey this cleanly. I think the best way to rule this is simply to add a max bonus. I would say, take your pick on that number, see which one works best.

- Max = sneak attack damage dice
- Max = rogue levels